# SQL Server 2017 I can't make a procedure

Tags: sql-server, backup, stored-procedures

Im quite new to this.
Im trying to make a procedure with recovery. But instead of making the procedure. It just recovers a database instead.

```
Use sde_sql
Go

Create Procedure RecoveryScript
as
    Alter Database SDE_SQL 
    SET Single_User with
    Rollback IMMEDIATE

    use master
    go

    Restore Database SDE_SQL
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\HF\Desktop\SQL\SQLDatabaseBackup.bak'
    WITH REPLACE, STATS = 5
```

Comment: You cannot put a `USE` statement inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Fred, Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Don't create the script in the database you are trying to restore.  Remove the use master.  The go after use master is why you are getting the behaviour you are.

Comment: The GO is ending your stored procedure.  The Restore portion is not included because it appears after the go.  Use sp_helptext RecoveryScript to see what you created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the word "GO" is the default batch separator. That tells SQL Server, "Alright, I'm done with this command, and go execute it."

So when you run this:

```
Create Procedure RecoveryScript
as
    Alter Database SDE_SQL 
    SET Single_User with
    Rollback IMMEDIATE

    use master
    go

    Restore Database SDE_SQL
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\HF\Desktop\SQL\SQLDatabaseBackup.bak'
    WITH REPLACE, STATS = 5
```

What you're really doing is this:

```
Create Procedure RecoveryScript
as
    Alter Database SDE_SQL 
    SET Single_User with
    Rollback IMMEDIATE

    use master
    go
```

SQL Server does that, and then thinks you're done, and starts this in a separate command:

```
Restore Database SDE_SQL
FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\HF\Desktop\SQL\SQLDatabaseBackup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, STATS = 5
```

If you want to create a stored procedure to restore a database, put that stored procedure in master itself (or in another database, but just not the one that's about to get restored, since you can't kill a connection while still running a query from it.) You won't need any "use database" commands in there at all.

Finally, as long as we're talking about restoring databases, check out [sp_DatabaseRestore](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/master#sp_databaserestore-easier-multi-file-restores) in the [open source First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/master). If you're using [Ola Hallengren's excellent maintenance scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) to take your backups, you can just point sp_DatabaseRestore at your backup folder, and it'll automatically restore the newest available backups of your database. (Disclaimer: I'm one of the contributors on the First Responder Kit repo.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your "script" just need to be executed once, so i see no need to create a stored procedure for it, so you just can put it as:

```
Alter Database SDE_SQL 
SET Single_User with
Rollback IMMEDIATE

use master
go

Restore Database SDE_SQL
FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\HF\Desktop\SQL\SQLDatabaseBackup.bak'
WITH REPLACE, STATS = 5
```

But if you really need to create this in a stored procedure, you can use BEGIN..END operators, and get rid of the USE and GO:

```
Use master
Go

Create Procedure RecoveryScript
as
BEGIN
    Alter Database SDE_SQL 
    SET Single_User with
    Rollback IMMEDIATE


    Restore Database SDE_SQL
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\HF\Desktop\SQL\SQLDatabaseBackup.bak'
    WITH REPLACE, STATS = 5

END

GO
```